# How to setup AWS Credentials in Python

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm trying to implement a program that uses the Amazon API. I've used the wrapper made by yoavaviram. I pushed my code to github and was notified my amazon that I shouldn't explicitly have my AWS credentials in my code. I've found some code that uses boto to access things like AWS's buckets and such but I don't think I need to use that. How can I pass in my credentials in the following code without explicitly writing their values in the code?

```
#windowShopping will take all of the Amazon HTMLs from a data structure and will retrieve all of the used/new prices
import re
import json
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from amazon.api import AmazonAPI
import time

AMAZON_ACCESS_KEY = < my access key >
AMAZON_SECRET_KEY = < my secret key >
AMAZON_ASSOC_TAG = < my user name >

asin_regex = r'/([A-Z0-9]{10})'
isbn_regex = r'/([0-9]{10})'

def get_amazon_item_id(url):
    # return either ASIN or ISBN
    asin_search = re.search(asin_regex, url)
    isbn_search = re.search(isbn_regex, url)
    if asin_search:
        return asin_search.group(1)
    elif isbn_search:
        return isbn_search.group(1)
    else:
        # log this URL
        return None

def get_amazon_product_meta(url):
    # the input URL is always of amazon
    amazon = AmazonAPI(AMAZON_ACCESS_KEY, AMAZON_SECRET_KEY, AMAZON_ASSOC_TAG)

    item_id = get_amazon_item_id(url)
    if not item_id:
        return None

    try:
        product = amazon.lookup(ItemId=item_id)        
    except amazon.api.AsinNotFound:
        # log this ASIN
        return None
    except Exception:
        return None


    # product.price_and_currency returns in the form (price, currency)
    # product_price = product.price_and_currency[0]

    new_price = product._safe_get_element_text("OfferSummary.LowestNewPrice.FormattedPrice")
    used_price = product._safe_get_element_text("OfferSummary.LowestUsedPrice.FormattedPrice")
    trade_in_price = product._safe_get_element_text("ItemAttributes.TradeInValue.FormattedPrice")

    if new_price or used_price or trade_in_price:
        return new_price, used_price, trade_in_price

    return Nonesting.Price.FormattedPrice

def unpickle(fileName):
    f = open(fileName, 'r')
    HTML_Dict = json.load(f)
    print(fileName)
    f.close()

    return HTML_Dict

def pickle(structure,fileName):
    f = open(fileName, 'w' )
    json.dump(structure,f)
    f.close()

def get_prices(urls,newPricesDict, usedPricesDict, tradeInDict):
    #iterates through document of book urls
    for url in urls:
        price = get_amazon_product_meta(urls[url])
        newPricesDict[url] = price[0]
        usedPricesDict[url] = price[1]
        tradeInDict[url] = price[2]
        time.sleep(1)
        print(url)
        print("\t" + str(price))


def main():
    newPrices = {}
    usedPrices = {}
    tradeInPrices = {}
    urlDict = unpickle('addresses.dat')
    get_prices(urlDict, newPrices, usedPrices, tradeInPrices)
    pickle(newPrices, "newPrices.dat")
    pickle(usedPrices, "usedPrices.dat")
    pickle(tradeInPrices, "tradeInPrices.dat")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Read it from a  environment variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a another file called `credentials.py` and
Define variables.

```
AMAZON_ACCESS_KEY = "access_key"
AMAZON_SECRET_KEY = "secret_key"
AMAZON_ASSOC_TAG = "tag_name"
```

Then in you file,

```
from credentials import *

AMAZON_ACCESS_KEY = AMAZON_ACCESS_KEY
AMAZON_SECRET_KEY = AMAZON_SECRET_KEY
AMAZON_ASSOC_TAG =  AMAZON_ASSOC_TAG
```

Comment: to make it even more explicit, DO NOT CHECK `credentials.py` INTO YOUR REPOSITORY. A `.gitignore` file can help.

Answer (score 1):

You should definitely use IAM credentials with EC2 Roles. It's a little harder at the beginning, but it pays. It ensures that credentials are rotated continuously.

I don't know the libraries you are using, but I can tell you that other libraries in python autodetect when they are run in a EC2 instance with IAM Roles assigned and they automatically load the corresponding credentials.